# How to provide wildcard in Bundle-ClassPath of Manifest.MF file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle, manifest.mf

I have a requirement where I do not know in advance how many third party jars would be required for my plugin (the third party jars have dependent jars which could increase of decrease in number). In the Bundle-Classpath, we can provide the exact relative path of jar. But, how can I provide a wild card to load all jars from a specific folder in my project.

I have tried below, but it didn't work for me.

Bundle-Classpath : lib/*.jar

Can it be done by some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for this. Each jar must be listed individually.

Possibly you could use separate plugin fragments to add additional jars.